How we generate a COG with Geotools?
I see there are few test cases to generate a tiled and even a BigTiff GeoTiff in GeoTools repository. E.g.

https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/d261ee2eec4022cb847d20aa5223e5a6c37992c7/modules/plugin/geotiff/src/main/java/org/geotools/gce/geotiff/GeoTiffWriteParams.java#L50

https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/plugin/geotiff/src/test/java/org/geotools/gce/geotiff/GeoTiffWriterTest.java#L634


But, is there any case were we can generate Cloud Optimize Geotiff?

A COG is just a GeoTiff with LZW compressed tiles, with internal overviews, so the standard writer ought to do with the Parameters set as described in the javadocs.
I can't work out how you would include the overviews explicitly or if they are automatically added for you.

That is not the whole truth. In COG the headers are ordered in a specific way so that information that is needed first is written into the beginning of the file. It may mean total rewrite of a "normal" tiled and compressed TIFF (LZW is not the only compression option). Especially adding overviews to existing GeoTIFF breaks the optimization. More information in https://gdal.org/en/latest/drivers/raster/cog.html#file-format-details.

that's very true.... so Ian, are in Geotools plans to support writing COGs out of the box?

We're always open to code contributions
